# IDEA, ошибка при создании классов или интерфейсов

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Сколько пользовался **IDEA** всегда все было хорошо. Но вот сегодня мне выбило такую ошибку (скриншот). В настройках ничего не трогал, буквально вчера все было хорошо.

> В чём может быть проблема? И как её решить? Заранее спасибо!

*P.S. По ответам в поиске прошёлся, однозначного решения нет.* 
[image: Вот такая ошибка]

[image: Версия]

Comment: Ошибка при попытке создания не только классов, но и при создании интерфейсов в том числе.
mark-и lbhtrnjhbb ничего не меняют.

Comment: 1. https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=unable+to+parse+template+class+intellij&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA791UA791&oq=unable+to+parse&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.5167j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: 2. Попробуйте переустановить IDEA

Comment: Может не на том месте хотите создать класс/интерфейс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите в Setting -> Editor-> file and code templates, выберите Class и вставьте в файле:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public class ${NAME} { }
```

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо! А в чём может быть дело? Почему я так понимаю "шаблоны" могли слететь, и где искать ответы если другие модули слетят тоже?